# replace getJSON jquery function with pure js using local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a getJSON jquery function that uses data from an external file  eg

```
$.getJSON( "data/dataset.json", function( data ) {
    var mygeojson = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [],
    };
    var waypoints = []
    var all_points=[]
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var lng = data[i].lng;

.....
```

I now have a local variable that contains the same data as the external data file.

eg

```
const dataset = [{..}, {..},......]
```

The data is in the exact same format.

How can I use a pure js function that references the dataset variable rather than the jquery getjson function?

Comment: Change the `dataset` variable name to `data` and remove the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a file with the following code as the data,

**datasetFile.js**

```
export const dataset = [{..}, {..},......];
```

and you have another file where you want to use this data

**useDataset.js**

```
import { dataset } from './datasetFile.js
console.log(dataset);
```

You should be good to go.